# Checking NSString's length

Tags: ios, nsstring

I think I am getting an error when I check my string length. It's only a recent thing since I updated my Xcode for the new iOS 6.

This is how I am checking my NSStrings length

```
if ([manuIdString length] != 0) {
```

Then when the thread hits this.. there is defiantly a value in manuIdString but I get this error.

```
2012-10-11 10:01:57.715 paranioa[8619:907] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f83ed60
2012-10-11 10:01:57.717 paranioa[8619:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f83ed60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x36b5b2a3 0x34e6b97f 0x36b5ee07 0x36b5d531 0x36ab4f68 0x25949 0x37f170ad 0x37f17135 0x37f170ad 0x37f1705f 0x37f1703d 0x37f168f3 0x37f16de9 0x37e3f5f9 0x37e2c809 0x37e2c123 0x36fdf5a3 0x36fdf1d3 0x36b30173 0x36b30117 0x36b2ef99 0x36aa1ebd 0x36aa1d49 0x36fde2eb 0x37e80301 0x1fb41 0x3b58cb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The exception message is pretty informative...

Comment: Does the dot notation fair any better? `manuIdString.length`

Comment: @Daniel no. They do exactly the same.

Comment: `manuIdString` is obviously not pointing to a string. Lots of things could cause that, but no way for us to diagnose why it's happening just from the error message.

Comment: Agreed. The exception is reporting that it's a `__NSCFNumber`, which means that manuIdString is an `NSNumber`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`manuIdString` is not an NSString.  You have accidentally assigned an `NSNumber` to it.

Comment: Or managed memory loosely and the pointer/the object behind it has been overwritten after an unexpected deallocation.

Comment: okay.. thank you.. I have recently just changed my coredata types from a basic NSData dump to the actual data types.. What confuses me is that I wouldnt be alerted to the fact I have passed a NSNumber or something similar into a NSStrin

Comment: Objective c is weakly typed.  While the compiler can catch many cases, you can assign an `id` to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I also faced this type of problem fetching values from json and assigning in NSString

Definitly manuIdString is not NSString.